# Elliptic Curves - Proving that the group is not cyclic

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have a question from Stinson: 7.14. The question states:

> Suppose that $p > 3$ is an odd prime, and $a,b$ is an element of $\mathbb Z_p$. Further, suppose that the equation $x^3 + ax + b$ is congruent to $0$ ($\mod p$) has 3 distinct roots in $\mathbb Z_p$. Prove that the corresponding elliptic curve group $(E, +)$ is not cyclic. **Hint:** Show that the points of order two generate a subgroup of $(E, +)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2$.

I've read through the elliptic curve material in the chapter preceding this question but I'm still a little hopeless. Can anyone explain or push me in the right direction on how to show/answer this?

I understand that points of order two (from the hint) follow the formula: $[2]P = \mathcal{O}$ but I'm not sure how this relates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain or push me in the right direction on how to show/answer this?

The first obvious thing to ponder is "what does it mean that a 'group is cyclic'?  What properties does a cyclic group have, that noncyclic groups do not?"

(Broader hint: a cyclic group has a generator; noncyclic (finite) groups do not)

> I understand that points of order two (from the hint) follow the formula: `2P = 0` but I'm not sure how this relates.

It relates quite a bit, actually.  Can a cyclic group have two different elements of order 2?

---

Update: since Dexter has solved the problem, I'll lay out the proof I was originally trying to suggest.

One fundamental property of all finite groups is that, if $n$ is the number of group elements, we have $xP = (x \bmod n)P$ (for any integer $x$ and any element $P$).

In addition, a finite group is cyclic if it has a generator, that is, an element $G$ for which all elements can be expressed as $xG$ (for some $x$).  In addition, for any $P$, we always have $xG = P$ for some $0 \le x < n$.  In particular, $xG \ne 0$ for any $0 < x < n$.

Now, for the group in question, we have two distinct elements $P_1$ and $P_2$, both of order two (actually, we have three, we only need two).  That is, $P_1 \ne P_2 \ne 0$, and $2P_1 = 2P_2 = 0$.

Now, suppose the group is cyclic; if so, we have a generator $G$.  We know $P_1$ can be expressed as $P_1 = x_1G$ for some $0 \le x_1 < n$.  We also have $2P_1 = 0$, that is, $2 (x_1 G) = (2 x_1)G = 0$.  We know that $(2x_1)G = (2x_1 \bmod n)G$, and if that is the neutral element, we must have $2x_1 \bmod n = 0$.  The only value $0 < x_1 < n$ that can satisfy that is $x_1 = n/2$ (which implies that $n$ must be even).

However, by the same reasoning, if we have $P_2 = x_2G$, we have $x_2 = n/2$, but that would mean that $P_1 = (n/2)G = P_2$, and so the two points of order two were the same, but we know they aren't.

Hence, there cannot be a generator, and hence the group cannot be cyclic.

This proof may sound a bit lengthy, however, that's mostly because I spelled out the logic quite explicitly, listing the various assumed properties of groups.  Once you get more acquainted with group theory, this logic would be more natural.

Comment: So a group is cyclic if it contains an element that, when raised to powers, calculates all of the other elements of that group... So I have to show that the group (E, +) is not cyclic by showing it has no generators?

Comment: @Dexter: that would work - how could you use the existence of two elements of order two to show that there cannot be a generator?

Comment: What is the group (E, +)?

Comment: Well I think that if two elements have both order two, would they have to equal because they both equal 0? Suppose 2P = 0 and 2Q = 0, that means 2P = 2Q => P = Q, but this can't be true correct?

Comment: The question says that the elliptic curve is mod p, which is an odd prime. If this is true, then the possible cycle length of generators is either 1 or of length p... Wouldn't this prove that the group is cyclic instead of not cyclic?

Comment: @Dexter: no; the size of the group is (generally) not $p$...

Comment: Sorry but this is where I start to get a little lost... I'm just not sure what I should be doing to solve/prove this

Comment: @Dexter:"Suppose 2P = 0 and 2Q = 0, that means 2P = 2Q => P = Q, but this can't be true correct?" - that is indeed not correct; in particular, in the curve in question, we have two (actually, three; four counting the neutral element) points $P, Q$ for which $2P = 2Q = 0$ but $P \ne Q$.  In fact, if the number of points on a curve is even, there will always be two distinct points for which $2P = 2Q$.

Comment: I think I found something... In the question, it states that there are three distinct roots, which means that points (x1, 0), (x2, 0), (x3, 0), and the neutral element must exist (You mentioned these points in an earlier comment). To test the order of these points, I can try point doubling. With each of those points with point doubling, I get 0 or the neutral element, which proves that those points all have order 2. Does this lead anywhere?

Comment: I also proved that the group z_2 x z_2 is non-cyclic, because it has 4 elements but all the elements have order 2 (none of them have order 4), which proves that it is indeed non-cyclic. How can I show that this is isomorphic to the subgroup generated by the four points?

Comment: Are the two groups isomorphic to eachother because both groups have only elements with order 2? Would that prove that, since z_2 x z_2 is non-cyclic, that the elliptic curve group is also non-cyclic?

Comment: @Dexter: that isn't quite enough to prove it, but consider what is $(x1, 0) + (x2, 0)$?  Hint: what is its order?  Is it $(x1, 0)$ or $(x2, 0)$?

Comment: Using the point addition formula, I got `(-x1 - x2, 0)` for the addition of those two points.

Comment: It's order is also of order two since 2 * (-x1 - x2, 0) = (0, 0)

Comment: @Dexter: so, it's not $x1$ or $x2$, but it's of order 2; what point is it?  Similarly, you can deduce what $x1 + x3$ is and $x2+x3$.  That (along with the identity additions) gives you the entire group table.  How does that table compare to the group table of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?  Can you form an explicit isomorphism?

Comment: I wrote out the point addition tables for both `Z_2 x Z_2` and the 4 points from the elliptic curve, and they both have the same ``format'' (I think that is the right word)... No element generates the entire group, does that table prove it?

Comment: @Dexter: an explicit isomorphism would do it.  Can you produce a mapping between the subgroup consisting of 0, (x1, 0), (x2, 0), (x3, 0)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ such that the group operation is preserved?  If you can, then the two groups must be isomorphic.

Comment: I can map the neutral element to (0, 0), and then provide a mapping between the other three elements to each other. Is that all I need to show? I'm sorry I'm just not very knowledgeable in this at all... :/

Comment: @Dexter: that works - once you have an explicit mapping (isomorphism) that preserves the group operation, you've proved that the two groups are the same.  I'll add in the proof direction I was originally suggesting to you (which didn't involve demonstrating an explicit $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroup)

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me through all of that, you've definitely helped me learn a lot. Sorry for all of the trouble